# Query needed to get an column values of one table which are not there in string column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables :

```
mysql> select * from quizquestionbank;


| ID | QuestionFilePath | CorrectAnswer |


|  1 | p.wav            |             1 |

|  2 | q.wav            |             2 |

|  3 | a.wav            |             3 |

|  4 | b.wav            |             1 |

|  5 | m.wav            |             3 |
```

Second table is :

```
mysql> select * from quizuserdetails;

| ID | MSISDN | QuestionIdDetails | AnswerRecord |

|  1 | 235346 | 1,3,4,5           | S,F,S,F      |

|  2 | 564574 | 4,5,67,88         | F,S,F,s      |

|  3 | 500574 | 5,55,66,44,2      | F,F,F,F      |
```

I want to get the IDs from table 1 which are not there in QuestionIdDetails column of second table.

I tried query 
`Select ID from quizquestionbank where ID not in (Select QuestionIdDetails  from quizuserdetails where msisdn = '235346 ');`

But this does not work 
CAn anybody suggest a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to match the id to the list, but that's not all:

```
Select disting qb.ID
from quizquestionbank qb
left join quizuserdetails qd
  on find_in_set(qb.id, QuestionIdDetails) > 0
  and msisdn = '235346'
where qd.id is null
```

There's 3 key things going on here:

1. using a left join and including the extra condition in the join condition
2. the use of `find_in_set()`, which finds a value in a CSV string, to make the join
3. using a where clause that filters out matches, leaving only the missed joins

Comment: I have one more Question related to this :
Suppose quizquestionbank table a datetime column, and i want to extract these records as per the above requirement ,but with an additional constraint that currentdate time should be less than the datetime in table :

does not work 
Select * from quizquestionbank where EndDate >(Select disting qb.ID
from quizquestionbank qb
left join quizuserdetails qd
  on find_in_set(qb.id, QuestionIdDetails) > 0
  and msisdn = '235346'
where qd.id is null)

Comment: You should probably [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) then